# tutorial or guide available on how to write a simple filter using akka http?

Tags: http, routes, akka

I have checked the akka http docs and have learned a lot about Directives and Routes.  But I have not found a simple example of how I can extract a value from a header  (say   user: joesmith)   and then do something like set that value in a threadlocal, then finally chain off to the rest of my routes.   If my goal is not clear, I'm happy to provide a little code with     and 'insert header grab' here comment to illustrate.

thanks in advance !

Comment: i think i'm getting close to figuring this out...  i might use headerValueByName  [ which i found in some old spray docs  http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/header-directives/headerValueByName/  ... hopefully there is something like this in akka http as well.]  will post a solution if i come up with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is insanely easy.  headerValueByName is the key to success.  Below is a hello world akka http that grabs the  'User'  header and displays it in the response:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer


object JunkServer {

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("junk-server")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val route =
    headerValueByName("User") { userId =>
      path("") {
    complete(
      HttpResponse(
        OK,
        entity = s"hello there: ${userId}")
    )
      }
  }



  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 9999)
  }
}
```

When you want to test it:

curl  -H "User: dracula"   localhost:9999

server response should be:

```
hello there: dracula
```